# Extjs listening for keydown event in grid

Tags: extjs4

In Extjs 4.1 I have an editable grid with listeners object where keydown event is caught for some purpose.my problem is when a cell is in edit mode my keydown listener function is not fired.I have no idea what's going on under the hood,any clue or solution will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If there is openned inline editor for grid cell all events are caught in this field and not propagated into any element of grid. In this case you have to handle keydown event in input field of the editor.